# Pagination with Slim Framework and Laravel's Eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel-4, twig, eloquent, slim

I'm using Slim Framework as router, Twig as Template Engine and Eloquent ORM to handle the database.

I created the bootstrap for these libraries.

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

/**
 * Laravel Eloquent ORM
 */
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;
use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
use Illuminate\Container\Container;

$database_capsule = new Capsule;

$database_capsule->addConnection([
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'database',
    'username'  => 'username',
    'password'  => 'password',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
]);

$database_capsule->setEventDispatcher(new Dispatcher(new Container));

$database_capsule->setAsGlobal();

$database_capsule->bootEloquent();

/**
 * Twig Template Engine
 */
Twig_Autoloader::register();

$twig_loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('template');

$twig_engine = new Twig_Environment($twig_loader);
```

And the routes:

```
/**
 * Slim Framework
 */
$application = new \Slim\Slim();

$application->get('/', function () use ($twig_engine) {

    $foods = Capsule::table('foods')->get();

    $index = $twig_engine->loadTemplate('index.html');

    echo $index->render(array('foods' => $foods));

});

$application->get('/page/:number', function ($number) use ($twig_engine) {

    $foods = Capsule::table('foods')->get();

    $index = $twig_engine->loadTemplate('index.html');

    echo $index->render(array('foods' => $foods));

});

$application->run();
```

What I want is: How can I paginate the results of:

```
$foods = Capsule::table('foods')->get();
```

Considering that I have "two" pages, the "/" and the "/page/1" for example.

And in each page I want in max 30 results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

starting from illuminate 4 you can do someting like this

```
$application->get('/page/:number', function ($number) use ($twig_engine) {

    $foods = Capsule::table('foods')->skip(30*$number)->take(30)->get();
    $index = $twig_engine->loadTemplate('index.html');

    echo $index->render(array('foods' => $foods));

});
```

a better solution is to include Illuminate\Pagination package and make it work with

```
Capsule::table('foods')->paginate(5)
```

however I don't know how to bootstrap Pagination class outside laravel.

Consider taking a look at https://github.com/zofe/rapyd-framework
It uses Slim, Twig, Eloquent, Symfony Forms.. but custom widgets for pagination.
(I'm the author)

Comment: Hey I am getting following exception in my Slim Framework Application, Can you please tell me the required dependencies(to put in my composer.json) to run this application.
`Type: ReflectionException
Code: -1
Message: Class paginator does not exist
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\workspace\shopping-demo\vendor\illuminate\container\Illuminate\Container\Container.php
Line: 501`

Comment: there is not a solution, basically "paginate" need laravel router.
I suggest you to leave Slim for the Laravel router (which is basically the symfony one): in this article you can find a way to bootstrap it:

http://www.gufran.me/post/laravel-illuminate-router-package-in-your-application

Answer (score 3):

1. Open `composer.json`
2. Add this line in require section:

   `"illuminate/pagination":"~5.0"`
3. Open your Ubuntu 14.04 terminal and go to your project's directory. Run `composer update` command. It will download your pagination library.
4. Add these both Lines in your model file

   `use Illuminate\Pagination;`

   `use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;`
5. In your controller place this code you will get paginated data.

   `$data = Student::paginate(5);`
6. In order to get paginated links in view file.

   `$students->links();`

Answer (score 0):

7- Don't forget to modify `currentPageResolver` and `currentPathResolver`. You can achieve this by using a simple middleware like the following.

```
<?php

namespace Mismar\Api\Middlewares;

use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Psr\Http\Server\RequestHandlerInterface as RequestHandler;
use Slim\Psr7\Response;

class PaginatorMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Example middleware invokable class
     *
     * @param  ServerRequest  $request PSR-7 request
     * @param  RequestHandler $handler PSR-15 request handler
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function __invoke(Request $request, RequestHandler $handler): Response
    {
        Paginator::currentPathResolver(function () use ($request) {
            return $request->getUri()->getPath();
        });
        Paginator::currentPageResolver(function ($pageName = 'page') use ($request) {
            return $request->getQueryParams()[$pageName] ?? 1;
        });

        return $handler->handle($request);
    }
}
```